# "Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = weights, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, : y and x different lengths"

Tags: r

I am trying to do *Program Evaluation* for my data set which is "growth" (basically it is the gdp of each country).

I have already ruled out all of the countries that do not have a complete set of data for the time period 1980-2000 so I am sure that I do not have any missing data.

After importing the data into R, I followed the instructions in the paper:
[An R Package for the Panel Approach Method for Program Evaluation: pampe by Ainhoa Vega-Bayo](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-2/vegabayo.pdf)

[This is a screen shot of how my data looks like in RStudio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xY7W.jpg)

```
> time.pretr<-c("1980", "1983")
> time.tr<-c("1984","1994")
> treated <-"SOUTHAFRICA"
> econ.integ<-pampe(time.pretr = time.pretr,time.tr = time.tr,treated = treated,data = growth)
Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = weights, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax,  : 
 y and x different lengths
```

What could I do to resolve this error and what does it mean when it says "y and x different lengths"?

Please note, this is my first time using R/RStudio so I am not familiar with the terms. If anyone could offer some help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to replicate the problem without [example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Error is coming from `leaps.setup` which is called from `pampe`, have a look at pampe function what arguments are being passed to leaps. Also, maybe relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5176002/680068

Answer (score 2):

My solution was the following:

x - has to be created using as.martix(your_data) and

y - has to be created as: your_data$target_column

Answer (score 1):

It appears `leaps` is very particular of the data structures used. As Александр Ласкорунский wrote he had to use those particular structures. I tried some experimenting and it seems that the `x` entry HAS to be a `matrix` data structure. Not a `data frame` or a `tibble` but specifically a `matrix`. For the `y` argument the structure MUST be a `vector`. I'm sure the more versed individuals in this area would be able to expand on this.

EDIE: Seems not only a vector but it has to be an atomic vector.